# Qt: how to call main window's pointer from another class?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to separate my roles in a game to different .cpp and .h files,
but I have trouble calling the pointer in mainwindow from another class, which I added through **scene->add()** in mainwindow.cpp.

It shows ***"player" was not declared in this scope*** when I run.

I know this question seems pretty basic, but I've tried my best to fix it with no results.

The following are main methods I've tried:

- add **MainWindow::** before player, but it shows the similar error
  that **mainwindow is not declared in this scope**.
- revise **player** to **this** pointer, and **it says that class Player has no such member.**
- revise **player** to **pos()** pointer, it says **pos() is not
  declared in this scope**
- set class Player as friend with main window, but nothing changes

Here is the code:

main window.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    scene(new QGraphicsScene(0,0,800,600)),
    timer(new QTimer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    player = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/img/whitedog.png").scaled(150,150));
    scene->addItem(player);
    player->setPos(0, 0);
    timer->start(10);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main window.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QKeyEvent>

#include "player.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    friend class Player;

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QTimer *timer;
    QGraphicsItem *player;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"

Player::Player()
{
}

void Player::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{

       switch(e->key()) {

       case Qt::Key_Up:
               player->setPos(player->x(), player->y()-10);
           break;
                 }
}
```

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QTimer>

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


class Player
{

public:
    Player();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

Comment: Where have you declared a Player object? Why does the player class have the keyEvent method if it does not inherit from any class?

Comment: Suggest you explain what's the function of player class & relation with the main window...What you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for advising. I declare "player" in mainwindow.h, which is a QGraphicsItem. And I plan to separate its function in class player, the keyEvent is to control the movement of the player. (When i press up, my player goes up in the game.)@eylianesc @Jiu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused between two different things.

You have a `class Player`, which I believe is the one that you want to declare in `mainwindow.h` but an object of `class Player` is not created anywhere( as far as what is shown above ).

The `player` currently declared in the `mainwindow.h` is of type `QGraphicsItem` and not of the `Player` class that you created, so you cannot expect your `keyPressEvent` to work on it.

You need to have a second look at your design, know the purpose of the `Player` class, it's responsibilities. Currently it is a simple class not inheriting from anything, did you want it to maybe inherit from `QGraphicsItem`.

In such a case, your class maybe could look something like this :

```
class Player : public QGraphicsItem
{
   //Players's responsibilities.
}
```

And in your `mainwindow.h`, you can just use the instance of the `Player` instead of using a `QGraphicsItem` instance.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  ...// other stuff
  private:
  Player *player;
}
```

**Additional Pointers :**

1 . I don't see a reason for the `Player` class to be a `friend` class in `mainwindow.h`, but then again it is your design.

2 . Prefer initializing the `player` object part in the member initialization list rather than doing it in the constructor.